# Git: follow merge when pulling new commits

Tags: git, merge

Let's say we have these branches:

- master
- develop
- new_feature

My local repo is following "new_feature".

Someone else has merged "new_feature" onto "develop", and deleted that branch on the server (i.e. the "new_feature" branch). As expected when the feature is finished.

I would like an automated/scripted way that detect that the branch has been merged, to which target branch, and that checkout that branch locally (and delete the local "new_feature" branch).

PS: the local change on the branch can be discarded in this simplified scenario.

Anyone?

Comment: Once it's merged and deleted, Git no longer tracks that branch, so I'm not sure this can be automated. You can ask Git what branches contains your current sandboxe's `new_feature` branch with `git branch --all --contains new_feature`, but only if no rebase removed your current branch head.

Comment: `git log --format=oneline --graph --decorate $(git branch --all --contains new_feature)` might also be useful: it will show you the log of every branch that contains your current `new_feature` head, but you'll have to manually look for the merges to find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a partial solution.

Detect if the pull work or not:

> if ! git pull --all --prune; then

The branch has been deleted, remotely, so no reference exists anymore. But we known what is the latest local and known commit of that (local) branch. Let's look where this commit has been merged (thanks to @joanis):

> ORIGIN=$(git branch --remotes --merged "HEAD" | grep -v HEAD)

The commit can appear twice, we strip out the " -> HEAD" line.
We need to find out what is the name:

> BRANCH="${ORIGIN/origin/}"
>
> BRANCH="${BRANCH// /}"

So let's go to the new branch:

> git checkout "$BRANCH"
>   git pull

The limit of this situation are if there are more than one branch in which it has been merged. This algorithm would pick one of them in the order in which it is listing by "git branch".